# TKinter Matplotlib plot not displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, networkx, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a TKinter app that displays a graph made with `networkx`, using `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, But the plot it not displayed, only a blank white square is displayed. Here is my program:

```
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.quit)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
    #canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=.5,rely=.4,anchor="center")
    root.title("Item Search")
    root.title_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30, weight="bold", slant="italic")
    root.configure(background="#00FFFF")
    label = Label(root, text = "Item Search", bg="#236B8E",fg="#67C8FF", height=2, width=root.winfo_height(),font=("Courier", 25))
    label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
    button1 = Button(root, text = "Load User Items", command = lambda:get_user_items(button2),height=2,width=11)
    button1.place(relx=.5,rely=.7,anchor="center")

    button2 = Button(root, text="Find the Shortest way", comman = find_shortest_way, height=2,width=15,state="disabled")
    button2.place(relx=.5,rely=.9,anchor="center")
    init()
```

init() function:

```
    item_db = pd.read_csv("all_items.csv")
    item_dict={}
    for shelf in item_db:
        for item in item_db[shelf]:
            if shelf != np.nan:
                item_dict[item] = int(shelf)
    store.add_node(0,pos=(1,1))
    store.add_node(1,pos=(1,0.5))
    store.add_node(2,pos=(1,0))
    store.add_node(3,pos=(2,0.5))
    store.add_node(4,pos=(2,0))
    store.add_node(5,pos=(3,1))
    store.add_node(6,pos=(3.5,0.5))
    store.add_node(7,pos=(4,0))
    store.add_node(8,pos=(4,2))
    store.add_node(9,pos=(5,2))
    store.add_node(10,pos=(5,0))
    store.add_edge(0,1,weight=1)

    store.add_edge(1,2,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(1,3,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(3,4,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(3,7,weight=2)
    store.add_edge(3,6,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(3,5,weight=2)
    store.add_edge(5,6,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(5,8,weight=2)
    store.add_edge(6,8,weight=3)
    store.add_edge(7,10,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(8,9,weight=1)
    store.add_edge(8,7,weight=4)

    pos=nx.get_node_attributes(store,'pos')
    nx.draw(store,pos,with_labels=True)
    labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(store,'weight')
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(store,pos,edge_labels=labels)

    plt.axis('off')

    fig1.canvas.draw()
```

How do I display the plot? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if you don't have to use `nx.draw(... ax=...)` to inform NetworkX that you already create matplotlib object and it has to use it to display graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this minimal example I have to use `nx.draw(..., ax=fig.gca() )` to display graph

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

root = tkinter.Tk()

fig = plt.Figure()
#sub = fig.add_subplot('111') 

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
#canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() #fill='both', expand=True)

G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
ax = fig.gca()  # it can gives list of `ax` if there is more subplots.
nx.draw(G, ax=ax)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

[image]

Other example which display NetworkX with other standard plots.

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

root = tkinter.Tk()

fig = plt.Figure()
sub1 = fig.add_subplot('311') 
sub2 = fig.add_subplot('312') 
sub3 = fig.add_subplot('313') 

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
#canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() #fill='both', expand=True)

data = [1, 3, 2, 4]
sub1.plot(data)

G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
nx.draw(G, ax=sub2)

data = [1, 3, 2, 4]
sub3.plot(data)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, just a simple mistake. tkinter is good library but difficult to work with as so few tutorials and the official documents is really bad

Comment: I added example which draws NetworkX graph between normal plots.

Comment: ya, got it. thank you very much. I was searching all over the internet for such small mistake. I just didn't knew to pass the `ax`.